# wordpress yoast og:url Not included in META

Tags: wordpress, seo, meta

Just started happening.. anyone have any ideas why the `OG:URL` would be missing from the Yoast meta in the `<head>`?

foreverphotographystudio.com

```
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v3.0.7 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
<meta name="description" content="Austin Wedding Photographer | Forever Photography Studio. Fine art Austin Wedding Photography by the best Austin Wedding Photographers"/>
<meta name="robots" content="noodp"/>
<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/+Foreverphotographystudio"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Austin Wedding Photographer | Forever Photography Studio" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Austin Wedding Photographer | Forever Photography Studio. Fine art Austin Wedding Photography by the best Austin Wedding Photographers" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Forever Photography Studio" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.foreverphotographystudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ForeverPhotographyStudioLogo.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Austin Wedding Photographer | Forever Photography Studio. Fine art Austin Wedding Photography by the best Austin Wedding Photographers"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Austin Wedding Photographer | Forever Photography Studio"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@FPS_photo"/>
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.foreverphotographystudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ForeverPhotographyStudioLogo.jpg"/>
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@FPS_photo"/>
<script type='application/ld+json'>{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"WebSite","url":"http:\/\/www.foreverphotographystudio.com\/","name":"Austin Wedding Photographer | Forever Photography Studio","alternateName":"Austin Wedding Photographer","potentialAction":{"@type":"SearchAction","target":"http:\/\/www.foreverphotographystudio.com\/?s={search_term_string}","query-input":"required name=search_term_string"}}</script>
<script type='application/ld+json'>{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"Organization","url":"http:\/\/www.foreverphotographystudio.com\/","sameAs":["https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ForeverPhotographyStudio","http:\/\/www.instagram.com\/foreverphotographystudio","https:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/company\/forever-photography","https:\/\/plus.google.com\/+Foreverphotographystudio","https:\/\/www.pinterest.com\/FPS_Photography\/","https:\/\/twitter.com\/FPS_photo"],"name":"Forever Photography Studio | Austin Wedding Photographer","logo":"http:\/\/www.foreverphotographystudio.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/12\/1518191_10151864082616924_1046507677_o.jpg"}</script>
<meta name="yandex-verification" content="68998b2e2c070db0" />
<!-- / Yoast SEO plugin. -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated "Yoast SEO" plugin to the latest version and it should be fixed.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

Answer (score -2):

check your header.php 
and add below line to it:

`<?php wp_head(); ?>`

Comment: The meta data he included is in the website, so wp_head() is in header.php. The Yoast SEO plugin just doesn't include the og:url meta anymore. I have the same problem and I'm trying to find out why. At least the Facebook Debug Tool gives a warning on the missing og:url.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/